# Can moral statements or theories be refuted?

Tags: ethics

I feel like moral statements cannot be refuted at least in the strictest sense of the term. Why? Because morality doesn't fully depend on logic and partially depends on emotions and normative (subjective) judgement. Therefore, it's never binary (true or false), but there exist a spectrum of what could be considered true or false, but only subjectively. Since there's no objective truth in morals, and it's not fully grounded in logic, it cannot be refuted, but only reasoned. What are the mainstream opinions on this? Is there an example of a moral statement or theory being refuted?

Comment: No statements can be refuted in isolation, they require other statements to fix the meaning and context. So we are talking about groups of statements, moral theories. And while *some* moral theories cannot be refuted for the reasons you describe, others can be, because they are simply incoherent. If a moral theory implies contradictory claims or gives contradictory prescriptions (and that may not be immediately obvious) can be refuted by showing that. As example, a moral theory that prescribes both "do not kill, ever" and "save lives of others, by any means available" is incoherent.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that moral judgments are relative or subjective. This itself is a controversial position.

Comment: "morality doesn't fully depend on logic " Obvious. "there's no objective truth in morals" Highly debatable.